# PyQt5 Перехват события виджета

Tags: python, qt, события, pyqt5

Нужно, чтобы при наведении мыши на элементы тулбара, не изменялось значение в статусбаре. Пытаюсь перехватить событие наведения мыши, но изменение строки в статусбаре все равно происходит.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys

class _FilterConstructor(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, _event):
        if _event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
            return True
        else:
            return QtCore.QObject.eventFilter(self, obj, _event)

 class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        menu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menu.addMenu('&File')

        evFilt = _FilterConstructor(fileMenu)
        fileMenu.installEventFilter(evFilt)

        self.statusBar().showMessage("line which doesn't want to disappear")

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication([''])
     root = MyWindow()
     root.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для объекта `QAction` есть специальное событие, описывающее действие обновления статусбара:

```
QtCore.QEvent.StatusTip
```

Соответственно, код конструктора фильтра будет выглядеть так:

```
class _FilterConstructor(QtCore.QObject):

def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(parent)

def eventFilter(self, obj, _event):
    if _event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.StatusTip:
        return True
    else:
        return QtCore.QObject.eventFilter(self, obj, _event)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lb = QtWidgets.QLabel("protected text")
self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(lb)
```

например можно добавить виджет в statusBar и выводить текст туда

Comment: Спасибо, можно так сделать. Но тогда теряется смысл в шаблоне статусбара. И хотелось бы понять, как это сделать через сигналы.